# Overwrite file with stdoutput from cron execution

Tags: cron, io-redirection

I have this cron in my crontab

```
00 01  *  *  * /srv/python/proj/acquisizione/acquisizioneAOK.sh >> /home/crontab_logs/acquisizioneAOK.out 2>&1; mailx -s "Cron output: acquisizioneAOK" marco.fumagalli@mymail.com < /home/crontab_logs/acquisizioneAOK.out
```

which writes the stdoutput to a file `.out` and then sends me an e-mail with that file as text.
How can I just empty the file from previous output? 
I just want an e-mail with the stdoutput of the last cron execution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To overwrite the log file on each execution of the script, replace the `>>` operator with the `>` operator.

The `>>` operator appends the output to the file on each execution, and you would have a continuously growing file with that approach.

The `>` operator 'clobbers' the file on each execution, which results in any existing data being removed before the redirected output is written.

Going one step further, you could simply pipe the output and error streams from the script to the `mailx` command directly :

```
/srv/python/proj/acquisizione/acquisizioneAOK.sh 2>&1 | mailx -s "Cron output: acquisizioneAOK" marco.fumagalli@mymail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirects of >> will append and > will overwrite. Just wondering though, if not keeping historical data, why not pipe it to mail?